# Query across multiple types using RavenDb

Tags: .net, ravendb, lucene.net

I am looking at raven db for the first time and Ive noticed there is some pretty powerful query capabilities, and even more so when using in combination with Lucene.net

Like the following example where you can use wildcards.

```
BlogPost[] prefixedResultsWithMatch = session.Advanced
.LoadStartingWith<BlogPost>("blogposts/1", "*/Author/*t");
```

One thing I would love to be able to do, is query across multiple object types.

For example if I had 'Customer' and 'Business' types both with a property 'Name', I want to be able to get ALL 'Customers' and 'Businesses' in a single call (even if the are not "related").

Is this possible with RavenDb and Lucene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about Lucene, but you can do what you ask for with a MultiMap index:

```
public class CustomerAndBusiness_ByName : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<CustomerBusiness>
{
    public CustomerAndBusiness_ByName()
    {
        AddMap<Business>(businesses => from business in businesses
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           business.Id,
                                           business.Name
                                       });

        AddMap<Customer>(customers => from customer in customers
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           customer.Id,
                                           customer.Name
                                       });

        Index(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And then query it like this:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var results = session.Query<CustomerBusiness, CustomerAndBusiness_ByName>()
                            .Where(x => x.Name == "Name")
                            .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<CustomerBusiness>()
                            .ToList();
}
```

This will of course only return a representation of the entities Business and Customer (called CustomerBusiness) and not the entities itself tracked by a unit of work.

Read more about it on Ayende's blog:

http://ayende.com/blog/89089/ravendb-multi-maps-reduce-indexes

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course I have found it spelled out in the documentation too....http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/client-api/querying/polymorphism